# boost locale iequals?

Tags: c++, boost, locale

How would I do case insensitive string comparison using boost locale?

Currently I do it like this, which seems rather inefficient:

```
boost::iequals(utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(lhs), utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(rhs));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the Boost.Locale collation API.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/collation.html